# Loading multiple external swf and navigate using buttons on child

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to load and unload many external swf files into main blank swf. And use navigation buttons (next/back) that located on the externally loaded child pages to navigate (load and unload pages).

I tried to dispatch event from child to main to unload. It works fine only with the first page, as the dispatcher is bubbling only once.

I have a default page to be loaded and dispatcher listener at the main swf as follows:

```
var cont:Sprite= new Sprite();

var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();

var swfFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Page1.swf"); //default page

addChild(cont);

swfLoader.load(swfFile);

cont.addChild(swfLoader);


swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoadedHandler);

function swfLoadedHandler(event:Event):void {

MovieClip(event.currentTarget.content).addEventListener("eventTriggered", removeLoader);

}


function removeLoader(event:Event):void {

SoundMixer.stopAll();
this.swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
this.removeChild(cont);
this.cont = null;


swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoadedHandler);

trace ("dispatched");

}
```

Also the next button code on child page1.swf is as follwos:

```
nxt_pg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_8);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_8(event:MouseEvent):void {

content_mc.gotoAndStop(1);

dispatchEvent(new Event("eventTriggered", true));

SoundMixer.stopAll();

//Code of Loading new page here
}
```

And the same code for back button.

So, I wonder if anyone could help me with code or better technique..Thanks in advance fore your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by removing Next and Back buttons from child SWFs and put it on container inside movie clip and change its visibility as needed.

At index page (page0.swf) I simply set 'buttons_mc.visible = false;' and make it visible at rest of pages.

The most important thing here is using 'addChildAt(myLoader,0)' instead of 'addChild(myLoader)' to make the buttons movie clip on top of the loaded SWFs.

All this done only on container code and no need to do any extra coding with the external loaded SWFs.

Below is the code for the container swf:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var swfNumber=0;
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("swf/"+"Page"+swfNumber+".swf");

buttons_mc.visible = false;
myLoader.load(myRequest);    
addChildAt(myLoader,0);// will be added under the buttons layer
trace(getChildIndex(myLoader));

//==============    

buttons_mc.nxt_pg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextSwf);
function nextSwf(event:MouseEvent){
    if(swfNumber<totalSwf){swfNumber++}
    else (swfNumber=0);
    reload();
    trace("Next");
    }

buttons_mc.prv_pg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, previousSwf);
function previousSwf(event:MouseEvent){
    if(swfNumber>1){swfNumber--}
    else (swfNumber=0);
    reload();
    trace("Back");
    }

//==============

function reload(){
    if (swfNumber==0){buttons_mc.visible = false;}
    else (buttons_mc.visible = true);
    myLoader.unloadAndStop();
    removeChild(myLoader);
    myRequest= new URLRequest("swf/"+"Page"+swfNumber+".swf");
    myLoader.load(myRequest);
    addChildAt(myLoader,0);
}
```